# Catch in python cx_Oracle DatabaseError DPI-1004: unable to get error message

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

I use cx_Oracle driver with SQLAlchemy to create engine.
Succesfully create enine like:

```
conn_string = 'oracle+cx_oracle://user:pass@host:1521/?service_name=some_service'
eng = create_engine(conn_string, encoding='utf8')
```

When I try to connect with:

```
eng.connect()
```

I catch the error:

```
DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) DPI-1004: unable to get error message
```

Using:

```
Python 3.5.2
cx-Oracle (6.2.1)  
SQLAlchemy (1.1.15)
```

Does anybody know solution?

Comment: That suggests something is seriously wrong with your Oracle client installation. Check that carefully and perhaps do a new instant client installation and point your PATH/LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to it. Failing that, provide some additional information on platform and Oracle Client installation.

Comment: I don't think so.
I successfully connected to another oracle databases.

Comment: For the databases you can connect to successfully, what happens if you change the username/password to an invalid combination? Do you then get ORA-1017? Or the same message as noted here?

Comment: I get `(cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied`

For previous comment, if you mean [ODPI-C Installation](https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html), I install 12.2 client for Windows.

Comment: Can you provide the other information that is available on the error -- specifically the "context" value?

Comment: [Here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/stm86FbrJG/) I provide full Traceback

Comment: Need the "context" value -- so try without sqlalchemy using the code posted in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved.
it needs to provide full TNS sting in create engine like:

```
eng = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://user:pass@full_TNS_string')
```

Comment: What does the "full_TNS_string" value look like? How does it differ from the value you had before?

Comment: For example `(DESCRIPTION=(LOAD_BALANCE=on)(FAILOVER=on)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=host1)(PORT=port1))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=host2)(PORT=port2))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=serv_name)))`

Comment: Ah, ok. I've added some additional debugging code to cx_Oracle. Would you be able to build cx_Oracle using the latest source code on GitHub and then retry the code that failed?

Comment: If I understand correctly, I should download **cx_oracle** through git (not pip) and try to get more informative error in SQLAlchemy?

Comment: Yes. Get the source of cx_Oracle using git and compile it, then use that version to get the more informative error. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Run a script that looks like this in order to determine the source of the issue:

```
import cx_Oracle

try:
    cx_Oracle.connect("user/pw@dsn")
except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as e:
    obj, = e.args
    print("Context:", obj.context)
    print("Message:", obj.message)
```

Comment: I don't catch exception in this case. Connection was successfully created.
But in _**sqlalchemy**_ I use a bit different format of connection string `oracle+cx_oracle://user:pass@host:1521/?service_name=some_service`.

Comment: Right. Well, add the try/catch block wherever you are getting the exception so that we can get more information. Without that information I can't help further!

Comment: I use SQLAlchemy, so my script: `try: con = engine_adb.connect()
except sa.exc.DatabaseError as e: print(e)`.
Output: `(cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) DPI-1004: unable to get error message`

Comment: Can you also print the context value? e[0].context?

Comment: As I use SQLAlchemy, e is sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError, so `e.orig.args[0].context = 'dpiConn_create: begin session'`

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that doesn't help. :-( I'm not sure how you can get that error -- the error that says you can't figure out the error that occurred! I'll ask internally and see if there is another way to diagnose this issue.